# Eclipse java built error - org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile incompatible with org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, rad

I'm getting the following eclipse error when perform project clean on a web project:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyAccount'.
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile incompatible with org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit

Any idea what could have caused this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any `.class` file in your project's source directory, or are all the files `.java`?

Comment: no, there is no .class file in source dir.  I saw that post from someone mentioned about that could caused similar type of error that I was seeing.  But anyway, the problem has mysteriously went away by itself.